# SSRS - Matrix, add page break after 25 rows, grouping/scope issues

Tags: reporting-services

I've got a Matrix, Zipcodes are the row groups, Facilities are the column groups.

I wanted to add a row group so that every 25 rows the table would page break.

I did this: `=Int((RowNumber(nothing)-1)/25)` as the Group source.  I feel like I need some proper scope like: `=Int((RowNumber("Zipcode")-1)/25)` but that doesn't seem to work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are there multiple rows per Zipcode or will there only ever be one row per Zipcode? Also, do you have any control on how the Dataset is generated, i.e. can you add extra columns to the Dataset if you need to?

Comment: Underlying data there are multiple rows per zipcode....aggregated on table it's 1 row per zipcode, generally 6 columns wide.

Comment: Is the underlying data generated with T-SQL? Can you change this if required?

Comment: Yeah, underlying data is in T-SQL, but I'm not sure how to change it and keep the affect of the matrix as the columns will change from report to report.  I built the data source to be very streamlined, it's zip, facility, number.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hack...If you add a header to your group and add an expression that is not hidden but has the same font as your background and set its value to: =Code.ResetRowNumber() -->see below.

In your groups you could add a grouping expression on Code.RowNumber() --> see below.

```
Public _rowNumber As Integer = 0

Public Function RowNumber() AS Integer    
    _rowNumber =_rowNumber + 1
    return _rowNumber    
End Function


Public Function ResetRowNumber() AS String    
    _rowNumber =0
    return ""    
End Function
```

Please note that I have only used this with one group without breaks and it would have to be tested on group breaks.